# How to show price in simple product on product view page?

Tags: simple-product, product-detail-page, product-view-page

I remove price from product view page using below line of code

```
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true" />
```

This is working perfectly.but **i need to show price in only simple product on product view page** and did not show in configurable,bundle,grouped,virtual product.

can someone help to achieve this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the below file

> catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="false" />
```

Use the above code to show the **price** only in the **simple product** on **product view page**

Answer (score 0):

Using **Preference**:-

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected $registry;

    protected $helperData;

    public function __construct(Context $context, SaleableInterface $saleableItem, PriceInterface $price, RendererPool $rendererPool, array $data = [], SalableResolverInterface $salableResolver = null, MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface $minimalPriceCalculator = null,\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,\Shineretrofits\CallForPrice\Helper\Data $helperData)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        parent::__construct($context, $saleableItem, $price, $rendererPool, $data, $salableResolver, $minimalPriceCalculator);
    }

    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        $current_product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if($current_product->getTypeId() == 'simple')
        {
                $result = parent::wrapResult($html);
        }else{
            $result = '';
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```